# How to write this sql query right?

Tags: sql, t-sql

> UPDATE Users 
>   SET Place = (SELECT COUNT(*)+1 AS [value]
>        FROM [Users] AS [t0]
>        WHERE COALESCE([t0].[Votes],0) > COALESCE(u.Votes,0)
>        )

Structure of Users table:

> Votes int, Place int

I just want set place for each user. For example: if you have high count of votes then you on the first place. If you have low count of votes then you on the last place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL Server 2005+

```
;with tmp as (
   select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by votes desc) rownum
   from users)
update tmp
set place = rownum
```